# Creating a Matrix in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

I am trying to create a 100 by 100 matrix that will be populated with 1's and -1's(at random), and the diagonal of the matrix should be all zeros.

I am new to python and numpy.

Comment: @That1Guy -- Try to be a little more constructive with you comment.  Bare "what have you tried" type comments are [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic)

Comment: @user2509830 -- That's a good start.  Can you post the code?  We can do a much better job showing you how to use the libraries if we can see how you've chosen to attack the problem.

Comment: so far, I have created a matrix with all 1's and -1's, but I can't get it to have zeros along the diagonal.

Also, when a matrix is created with numpy, how do i access the values( if i wanted to sum up values in a matrix)?

Comment: In addition to the answers below you should probably read this page: `http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/BuildingArrays`

Answer (score 3):

To create the matrix with ones:

```
a = numpy.ones( (100,100) )
```

To create the random matrix:

```
a = numpy.random.random( (100,100) ) # by default between zero and one
```

To set all the diagonals to zero:

```
numpy.fill_diagonal(a, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. After the matrix is created, how can i access values inside the matrix? 
for instance, is the value in the 2nd row, 3rd column just
example_matrix[2][3]?

Comment: essentially, but python uses a 0 to index the first element, so the 2nd row, 3rd column, so it would be example_matrix[1][2]

Comment: @user2237635 That is true for python's lists of lists, but a multidimensional numpy array is indexed like `[x,y]`, not `[x][y]`

Comment: Isn't there a `numpy.fill_diagonal`?

Comment: `http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html` New in 1.4.0 and likely a lot faster since the indices are never constructed. Just uses fancy slicing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple python line to create a 2D matrix - 100X100:

```
  yourmatrix = [[0 for x in xrange(100)] for x in xrange(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, just using list comprehension and random:

```
from random import randint
x = [1,-1]
my_matrix = [[x[randint(0,1)] if i!=j else 0 for i in range(100)] for j in range(100)]
```

This will give you the random choice between -1 and 1 with 0 for the diagonal. You can embed this in a function to give you a matrix of NxN size as follows:

```
from random import randint
def make_matrix(n):
    x = [-1,1]
    return [[x[randint(0,1)] if i!=j else 0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```